# GWT 2.8.0 migration issue

Tags: gwt, jetty

I am working on migrating our Application from GWT 2.1.0 to GWT 2.8.0. I am using org.codehaus.mojo gwt-maven-plugin for building the project and the built application works fine after deployment in the tomcat instance. The problem is with the eclipse IDE. I am using GWT Eclipse Plugin (V3) and Eclipse neon. Here GWT compile works fine but when I try to run in SuperDev or DevModeWithJetty I am facing the below error.

```
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.<init>(ServerConnector.java:96)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:122)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:161)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:102)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.SuperDevListener.runCodeServer(SuperDevListener.java:112)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.SuperDevListener.start(SuperDevListener.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.ensureCodeServerListener(DevMode.java:664)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.doStartup(DevModeBase.java:810)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:549)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:913)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:706)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:430)
```

There is no clear info about which class is incompatible. Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is my maven dependency tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ prj-web ---  
[INFO] com.prj:prj-web:war:4.5.0.52-SNAPSHOT  
[INFO] +- com.prj:prj-core:jar:4.5.0.52-SNAPSHOT:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.2:compile  
[INFO] |  +- commons-chain:commons-chain:jar:1.2:compile  
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-
core:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3:compile  
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.45:compile  
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.2.0:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.6.4:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile  
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.7:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.5:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.7:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.7:compile  
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile  
[INFO] |  +- com.tmon:tmon-logger:jar:3.0.6:compile  
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.0:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile  
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.3.0:compile  
[INFO] +- com.prj:prj-core:test-jar:tests:4.5.0.52-SNAPSHOT:test  
[INFO] +- com.prj:prj-jedeai:jar:4.5.0.52-SNAPSHOT:compile  
[INFO] +- com.prj:prj-prjmarkets-services:jar:4.5.0.52-SNAPSHOT:compile  
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.0:compile  
[INFO] +- com.prj:prj-prjmarkets-services:test-jar:tests:4.5.0.52-SNAPSHOT:test  
[INFO] +- com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.8.0:provided  
[INFO] +- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.8.0:provided  
[INFO] |  +- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:jar:1.0.1:provided  
[INFO] |  +- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:jar:sources:1.0.1:provided  
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:provided  
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided  
[INFO] |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:provided  
[INFO] +- com.google.gwt.inject:gin:jar:2.1.2:compile  
[INFO] |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile  
[INFO] |  \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:jar:3.0:compile  
[INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile  
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile  
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile  
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile  
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile  
[INFO] +- com.ged.srm:sarima-web-services-client:jar:4.4.0:compile  
[INFO] |  \- com.ged.srm:sarima-security-context-provider:jar:4.4.0:compile  
[INFO] |     +- com.ged.srm:sarima-web-services-api-c:jar:4.4.0:compile  
[INFO] |     +- com.ged.srm:sarima-util:jar:4.4.0:compile  
[INFO] |     +- com.ged.srm:sarima-security-engine:jar:4.4.0:compile  
[INFO] |     \- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.1:compile  
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile  
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile  
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:test  
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile  
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile  
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6

[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile  
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:0.9.24:compile  
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:0.9.24:compile  
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile  
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile  
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.7:compile  
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.7:compile  
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:3.0-alpha-1:provided  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:test  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.2.143:compile  
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.5.Final:compile  
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile  
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile  
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile  
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.5.Final:compile  
[INFO] |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile  
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile  
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.0.2.GA:compile  
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:3.6.5.Final:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:jar:3.2.0.ga:compile  
[INFO] |     +- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:compile  
[INFO] |     +- freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.8:compile  
[INFO] |     \- org.hibernate:jtidy:jar:r8-20060801:compile  
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile  
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.2.1:compile  
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:22.0:compile  
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.0.18:compile  
[INFO] |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile  
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava-gwt:jar:20.0:compile  
[INFO] +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile  
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile  
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-js:jar:2.0.8.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile  
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile  
[INFO] +- org.tuckey:urlrewritefilter:jar:3.1.0:compile  
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:provided  
[INFO] +- javax.el:el-api:jar:1.0:provided  
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6.2:compile  
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-stream:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-ftp:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.0:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-sftp:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:test  
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit-dep:jar:4.8.2:test  
[INFO] +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:3.6:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-ejb_2.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile  
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile  
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile  
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1:compile  
[INFO] +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile  
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.0:test  
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test  
[INFO] +- com.tibco:tibcrypt:jar:5.1.0:compile  
[INFO] +- com.tibco:tibjms:jar:5.1.0:compile  
[INFO] +- com.tibco:tibjmsadmin:jar:5.1.0:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:jar:5.4.2:test  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:test  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:activeio-core:jar:3.1.2:test  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:kahadb:jar:5.4.2:test  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:jar:1.1:test  
[INFO] |  +- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.1.0:test  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:test  
[INFO] |  +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.6:compile  
[INFO] |  \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:4.0.1:test  
[INFO] +- org.lazyluke:log4jdbc-remix:jar:0.2.5:test  
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-utilities:jar:2.5.9:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.4:compile  
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-rm:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-management:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.1.4:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security-saml:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.1.4:compile  
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.0.5:compile  
[INFO] |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-profile-api:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-core:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-api:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-api:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- org.cryptacular:cryptacular:jar:1.0:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.51:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  \- net.shibboleth.utilities:java-support:jar:7.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-api:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-impl:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-api:jar:3.1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile  
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.9.0:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.1.4:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.1.4:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings:jar:2.1.4:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax:jar:2.1.4:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-resolver:jar:1.0:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.2:compile  
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile  
[INFO] |  |  |  \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0.1:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-common:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.11:compile  
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-core:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-validator:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-javascript:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-javascript:jar:3.1.5:compile  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.4:compile  
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.4:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-nodeps:jar:1.8.1:compile  
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:jar:0.6.1:compile  
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:0.6.1:compile  
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.6.1:compile  
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.1.5:test  
[INFO] |  \- info.cukes:cucumber-core:jar:1.1.5:test  
[INFO] |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-html:jar:0.2.3:test  
[INFO] |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:jar:1.0.3:test  
[INFO] |     \- info.cukes:gherkin:jar:2.12.1:test  
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.1.5:test  
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-spring:jar:1.1.5:compile  
[INFO] +- org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:1.0.6:test  
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ftpserver:ftplet-api:jar:1.0.6:test  
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:2.0.4:test  
[INFO] \- org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:jar:1.8.6:test  
[INFO]    +- org.apache.pdfbox:fontbox:jar:1.8.6:test  
[INFO]    \- org.apache.pdfbox:jempbox:jar:1.8.6:test
```

Comment: Looks vaguely like a dependency issue; probably still have some old jars in your project. Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Here is my project's dependency tree

Comment: You're missing gwt-dev from your classpath. Please note that the classpath of GWT 's eclipse plugin can be different from that of maven (you can check it via Run Configurations).
Also, why 2.8.0 and not 2.8.1?

Comment: @Andrei thanks for your reply. I have tried using the gwt-dev from my maven repo instead of embedded one from GWT Eclipse plugin. but still the error is there :(

Comment: The exact same error? Also, what do you get when you run via cmd line? (`mvn gwt:run`) Trying to figure out if this is a Maven problem or Eclipse problem.
Also, which Java version are you using?

Comment: regarding mvn gwt:run, I have never tried this cmd before. but when I try now jetty server is up and running. I am using java 8